# scan-build doesn't find "variable is used uninitialized"

Tags: c, static-analysis, kdevelop, clang-static-analyzer, scan-build

I am trying to find bugs in reviewed project using scan-build tool. Its output report seems just perfect to send to author of code. Tool finds some good warnings.

I also use KDevelop 5.0.3 and it shows me even more warnings. Specifically it reports multiple "Variable 'pkginfo_handle' is used uninitialized whenever 'if' condition is true [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]". I believe that KDevelop parser is backed by clang, but I don't know how this works

command I use for running tool:

```
    scan-build gcc -c **/*.c  -I (multiple directories to headers)
or 
    scan-build clang -Wall **/*.c  -I (multiple directories to headers)
```

I checked that **/*.c covers the file where KDevelop finds problems.

Can I persuade scan-build to look for this error as well?

Comment: -Wsometimes-uninitialized is a warning from plain Clang. Make sure that this compiler flag is added in your build system when Clang is used, then scan-build should print out these warnings as well.

Comment: And yes, since KDevelop 5.0, C++ is backed by Clang, thus you get the detailed warnings in the IDE.